# Alternative to Import-AzWebAppKeyVaultCertificate in Azure Rm

Tags: azure, powershell

Planning to import an SSL certificate to a web app from Key Vault.

Found that  Import-AzWebAppKeyVaultCertificate in Az.websites which performs the above task but the above fails in the azure pipeline and I'm looking into any alternative in AzureRm As for my research I can't find anything in documents.

Az docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/import-azwebappkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-6.0.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-4.8.0

I want to know anything specific command to import ssl certificate to a web app from keyvault using AzureRm commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate) command ?

```
az login

# upload certificate to Azure key vault
az keyvault certificate import --file "E:\Cert\P2SChildCert.pfx" --password "" --name "test1234" --vault-name "testkey08"

# download certificate as pfx file
az keyvault secret download --file "test2.pfx" --vault-name "testkey08" --name "test1234" --encoding base64

# upload the pfx file to Azue web app
az webapp config ssl upload --certificate-file "test2.pfx"  --name "andywebsite" --resource-group "andywebbot"  --certificate-password "" --query thumbprint --output tsv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Searching for commands to import from keyvault to app service directly rather than uploading from the path.

Comment: empty string password is not accepted. getting error "argument --certificate-password: expected one argument"

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1) to call the REST API [`Certificates - Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/create-or-update) manually.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/{name}?api-version=2019-08-01
```

To get the access token, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#client-credentials-grant-non-interactive-clients